# Why I am not getting into the path file " the system cannot find the path specified "

Tags: python, shutil, os.path, pathlib

So I am using a function in python which is being called in Robotframework to copy a file from a source to destination 
I have used os.path.join() and os.listdir() and os.path.normpath() to get access to the folder and copy using shutil
But everytime I get this error

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\10.28.108.***\\folder\\folder2\\out/*.*'
```

My code

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import os

#filename = Path ("\\10.28.108.***\folder\folder2\out\001890320181228184056-HT.xml")

source = os.listdir("\\10.28.108.***\folder\folder2\out")
destination = "\\10.28.108.***\folder\folder2\"
for files in source :
    if files.endswith(".xml"):
        shutil.copy(files, destination)
```

Answer (score 1):

By this you can read your file.

```
filename = secure_filename(file_name.filename)
file_split = os.path.splitext(filename)
filename = file_split[0] + '__' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + file_split[1]
filepath = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
syspath = os.path.join(upload_dir, filepath)
file_name.save(syspath)
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing here that check if you can access this folder(\10.28.108.\folder\folder2\out) from your file explorer

The other thing is you have to specify two slash if you are accessing remote folder below is example:

```
source = os.listdir(r"\\10.28.108.xxx\folder\folder2\out")
```

Comment: If I try the same for system path its working fine , but for remote directory it behaves differently ,